# Index a data.table using a list of row numbers in i

Tags: r, data.table

Given a data.table and a list of unknown length consisting of different length numeric vectors that represent likely (but not certain) row indices, is there a data.table-idiomatic way to extract a list of data.table objects of those rows?

```
dt <- data.table(a = 1:10, b = 101:110)
idx <- list(`0` = 1:5, `1` = 5:8, `2` = 6:10)
idx2 <- list(`0` = 1:5, `1` = 5:8, `2` = 6:11) # Ex. with invalid row number
```

I can get the desired result with lapply, but I wonder if I'm not missing something more appropriate.

```
lapply(idx, function(x) dt[x])

# $`0`
# a   b
# 1: 1 101
# 2: 2 102
# 3: 3 103
# 4: 4 104
# 5: 5 105
# 
# $`1`
# a   b
# 1: 5 105
# 2: 6 106
# 3: 7 107
# 4: 8 108
# 
# $`2`
# a   b
# 1:  6 106
# 2:  7 107
# 3:  8 108
# 4:  9 109
# 5: 10 110
```

(I'm not against going further back to get something more elegant -- the overall goal is to extract a data.table for each consecutive set of missings in a single column, given a buffer on either side of a predetermined length (say 4). Right now, I extract the row numbers of the consecutive missings into a list, add the buffer on either side, and use that to create the vector of row numbers. Below is my method of getting at the indices in the first place:)

```
dt <- data.table(a = c(1:4, NA, NA, 7:12, NA, 14:18), b = 101:118)

splitIntoConsecutive <- function(missvec){
  whichmiss <- which(missvec)
  split(whichmiss, cumsum(seq_along(whichmiss) %in% (which(diff(whichmiss) > 1) + 1)))
}

indexWithLeadLag <- function(consec, veclen, desired.window = 4){
  max(consec[1] - desired.window, 1):min(tail(consec, 1) + desired.window, 17)
}

missvec <- dt[, is.na(a)]
consecs <- splitIntoConsecutive(missvec)
idx <- lapply(consecs, indexWithLeadLag, length(missvec))
```

Comment: It doesn't seem appropriate to keep duplicate copies of the data. What is the end goal of splitting up the data.tablel?

Comment: @sindri_baldur You're very right that I'm already working outside the data.table idiom in this case because I'm creating copies here, but it's necessary as these will be modified by reference (and sequentially) but may contain overlapping rows. If the first buffered NAs contains rows 1:10 and the second buffered NA contains rows 9:17, modifying the first by reference has the potential to give me different results for the second because of their shared row.
Possible to create the copy in the *next* step which occurs within a function. Until now I've done it thusly to preserve oversight.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Is there an issue with your approach?

Comment: @Roland Within a simulation study, I'm calling this around 800k times, although I will admit this is not the largest bottleneck. I have a hunch that a more efficient and elegant data.table solution exists but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

The additional `which()` and `%in%` in the indexing can help with your `idx2` case where the list may contain additional reference indices that are not valid rows in your data.table. This then avoids NAs and produces the same output as the `idx` case so should be a more general solution.

`lapply(idx2, function(x) dt[x[which(x %in% as.numeric(rownames(dt)))]])`